# wpf disable swiping windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-8, swipe

I am building a wpf touch oriented app for windows 8 and I need to remove the posibility of accidentally swiping the left edge of the screen and end up in another application not meant for the user. Is there a way to disable this for this specific application? Perhaps programatically. I have the same problem with the charm bar. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on below link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualstudiogeneral/thread/1882cba3-8e6a-44c7-a1ba-b309e469aef8
I think rather than stackoverflow you should go for msdn forum

Comment: Thank you but I am the one that asked the question on msdn :)